# Django Audio Player

Tags: django, html5-audio

I am working on a django music app and I have a model called Song.

```
class Song(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
    audiotrack  = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
    likes       = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,related_name='track_likes')
```

---

It gets passed in the template as an object list.

```
def list_view(request):
    songs = Song.objects.all()
    context = {
        'tracks_list' : songs
    }
    return render(request,"musica/list.html",context)
```

---

In the template, I for-loop through the objects and link them to the audio player.

```
<audio id="player" src="{{ object.audiotrack.url }}"></audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"></button>
```

---

And this is the problem.

The buttons remain the same, and play always one and the same track.

I have a like button already for the songs, which is a ManyToMany Field.

```
class TrackLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get("id")
        obj = get_object_or_404(Song,id=id)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
        return url_
```

Do I need to make something similar for the play button?
A OneToOne Field called playing which toggles the audio player?

But how is this going to work in the template, considering the player link:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"></button>
```

---

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine the getelementbyid is the issue, all of the looped through audio tags have the same id so JS just starts playing the first one.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I found another solution